# How do I rescue a stranded rover?

Tags: surviving-mars

I've got an RC Explorer that ran out of power away from a base. How do I recharge it so it can get back home? I've tried building a power cable underneath it, didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send any other RC (remote-controlled) near the unit that ran out of power. Then, select it (left-click) and use the **recharge** option in the UI.

[image]